# How to install additional dependencies in Tensorman

Tags: python, docker, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning

I am on popos 20.04 LTS and I want to use [Tensorman](https://support.system76.com/articles/tensorman/) for tenserflow/python. I'm new into docker and I want to install additional dependencies for example using default Image I can run jupyter notebook using these commands -

```
tensorman run -p 8888:8888 --gpu --python3 --jupyter  bash

jupyter notebook --ip=0.0.0.0 --no-browser
```

but now I have to install additional dependencies for example if I want to install [jupytertheme](https://github.com/dunovank/jupyter-themes) how can I change that ? I have tried to install it directly inside docker container but its not working that way.

this [issue](https://github.com/pop-os/tensorman/issues/12) is looking similar to my problem but there was no explanation exactly how I have to make custom image in tensorman.

Comment: Is jupytertheme a desktop theme or a tensorman theme?

Comment: @JRichardsz as I've mentioned in the question I want to install additional dependencies, it is just an example it is just a python package I have given github link you can check by clicking on that link about that package
but its not the main point of my question you can use any other package in the answer It is just an example which I have given to explain what I want to do

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to install dependencies.

1. Create a custom image, install dependencies and save it.
2. Use the `--root` tag to gain root access to the container, install dependencies and use them.

## Build your own custom image

If you are working on a project and want some dependencies for that project or just want to save all your favourite dependencies, you can create a custom image according to that project and save it and later use that image for your project.

Now make a list of all packages once you are ready use this command

```
tensorman run -p 8888:8888 --root --python3 --gpu --jupyter --name CONTAINER_NAME  bash
```

Where `CONTAINER_NAME` is the name of the container you can give any name you want and `-p` sets the port (you can search about port forwarding in docker)

Now you are running container as root, now in the container shell use.

```
# its always a good idea to update the apt, you can install packages from apt also
apt update

# install jupyterthemes
pip install jupyterthemes

# check if all your desired packages are installed
pip list
```

Now it's time to save your image

Open a new terminal and use this command to save your image

```
tensorman save CONTAINER_NAME IMAGE_NAME
```

`CONTAINER_NAME` should be the one which was used earlier, and for `IMAGE_NAME` you can choose according to your preferences.

Now you can close the terminals use `tensorman list` to check your custom image is there or not. To use your custom image use

```
tensorman =IMAGE_NAME run -p 8888:8888 --gpu bash

# to use jupyter
jupyter notebook --ip=0.0.0.0 --no-browser
```

## Use `--root` and install dependencies

Now you might be wondering that in a normal Jupyter notebook, you can install dependencies even inside the notebook, but that's not the case with tensorman; it's because we're not running it as root because if we run it as root, exported files in host machine would also be using root permissions that's why it is good to avoid using `--root` tag but we can use that to install dependencies. After installing, you have to save that image (it's not necessary though you can also install them every time) otherwise, installed dependencies will be lost.

In the last step of the custom image building, use these commands instead

```
# notice --root
tensorman =IMAGE_NAME run -p 8888:8888 --gpu --root bash

# to use jupyter, notice --allow-root
jupyter notebook --allow-root --ip=0.0.0.0 --no-browser
```